# How to get a list of installed android applications and get permission for each application and pick one to uninstall?"

Tags: android, permissions, get, uninstallation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get App's Permission for each app? how to do it programmatically on Android ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385957/how-to-get-apps-permission-for-each-app-how-to-do-it-programmatically-on-androi)

How I get "App's Permission" and show "App's Permission" List and uninstall for each application on Android.

Sorry I ask not good.
I want to ask "How to get a list of installed android applications and get permission for each application  and pick one to uninstall?"

Now,I'm developing for Android App.
How to get "App's Permission" for each application.
I want to show list Application that show list "App's Permission" for each application

You understand me??

And.... I want to uninstall application that to show list application.
I want to example code for Android

Sorry Again for I ask not good.
I'm not dominant in English.
:)

Please.

Thank you.