# How to get App's Permission for each app? how to do it programmatically on Android?

Tags: android

How to get App's Permission Detail for each app? how to do it programmatically?

I want to display **"App's Permission Detail for each app"** on TextView.
But I try it but Not Ok??

Hello.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.*;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.*;

public class HelloSakez extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

final Intent mainIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
mainIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
final ListView lw = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
final List<ResolveInfo> pkglist = lw.getContext().getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(mainIntent, 0);
final TextView tw = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
Iterator it = pkglist.iterator();
while(it.hasNext()){
ResolveInfo rf = (ResolveInfo)it.next();
tw.append(rf.toString());
}
}
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<Button android:text="Button" android:id="@+id/button1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></Button>
<ListView android:id="@+id/listView1" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="fill_parent"></ListView>
<TextView android:text="TextView" android:id="@+id/textView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: please, give us more information. It is very difficult to understand what is your problem. Do you want to write an application which shows a list of applications with their permissions and ability to uninstall?

Comment: Exactly, what do you want to know, how to get permissions, show permissions, or uninstall applications..?

Comment: @Vladimir Ivanov
Yes!! I want example code for android.

Comment: @Mudassir what do you want to know, how to get permissions, show permissions, or uninstall applications..? –

I want to example code for each question.
Because I am trying to find out 3 days ago. >///<
I decided to ask questions.

Sorry for I ask not good.
Thank you for interesting my question.
:)

Comment: This question is a bit vague. Consider to ask one question to a specific problem, not three big questions inside one post.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use PackageManager's [GET_PERMISSIONS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#GET_PERMISSIONS) flag.

Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3280632/119895).

Answer (score 18):

#### Use the following code in your activity:

I created `StringBuffer appNameAndPermissions = new StringBuffer();` to append all the apps and permisssions info.

It's working fine. I tested it already. If you have any issues, please let me know.

```
StringBuffer appNameAndPermissions = new StringBuffer();
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

for (ApplicationInfo applicationInfo : packages) {
    Log.d("test", "App: " + applicationInfo.name + " Package: " + applicationInfo.packageName);
try {
    PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(applicationInfo.packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);
    appNameAndPermissions.append(packageInfo.packageName+"*******:\n");

    //Get Permissions
    String[] requestedPermissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;
    if(requestedPermissions != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < requestedPermissions.length; i++) {
            Log.d("test", requestedPermissions[i]);
            appNameAndPermissions.append(requestedPermissions[i]+"\n");
        }
    appNameAndPermissions.append("\n");
} catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

#### Use the following permission in your AndroidManifest.xml file:

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>`

Comment: why do you need this persmission? you don't use it here. Also, you don't need to use StringBuffer, as you don't have multiple threads running... About the permissions, I think you can use "loadLabel" so that they will have the same name as shown to the user.

Comment: For some reason, when using the call to "getInstalledApplications" that you had, I get null for applicationInfo.name

Answer (score 0):

Zhocker

To uninstall any app use below code

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DELETE);
i.setData(Uri.parse("package:com.package name"));
startActivity(i);
```

And to get permissions use [getInstalledPackages(int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getInstalledPackages%28int%29) with the flag [GET_PERMISSIONS](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#GET_PERMISSIONS)

Answer (score -3):

1. For App's permission go to **Manifest** file ans see.

2.for uninstall the app follow the below points:-

a. go to **setting** 
b. then Open **Application**
c. then open **Manage Application**
d. then choose the **app** which you want to Uninstall
e. then click on **Uninstall** and Uninstall the app.

Comment: Oh >///< 
How I get "App's Permission" and show "App's Permission" List and uninstall for each application on Android.

Sorry I ask not good.

How to use code for get "App's Permission" and show "App's Permission" List and uninstall for each application on Android.

Example Code for me.
please. 

I want to ask that.
Thank you for answer me. AndroidDanger

Do you know answer for new question??
answer me. please

Comment: Buddy, not downvoted but he is asking about how to do it programmatically?

Comment: @Mudassir I want that you say.
I am trying to find answer for my question. 3 day ago. Haha
I find link that is 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2695746/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-android-applications-and-pick-one-to-run)

But I am newbie for android programming.
I studied it about a week.
I have a problem, so this point could not be developed.

Now!! I am trying to find answer for my question.
:)

Comment: @Zhocker: The link you mentioned is about getting the list of installed apps while you are asking about permissions. I don't clearly understand what do you want?

Comment: @ Mudassir
I want to example code to show list of installed apps.

Why I are asking about permissions"?
Answer : I want to show list of installed apps that show detail about permissions for each apps.

I want example code about that. 
You understand me? :)