# How can I analyse a Apk file in android application? Get the permissions

Tags: android

I want to write an android app which can analyse the APK file and output the  permissions this application required? I saw some app achieve this and can anyone tell me which method they might used? thanks

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385957/how-to-get-apps-permission-for-each-app-how-to-do-it-programmatically-on-andro

Comment: @AsifMujteba It seem to analyse installed app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **best** way of doing it with external apk files, **not** the installed ones:

The `.apk` file is a casual `.zip` with  changed extension. The permissions are located in `AndroidManifest.xml` file, so your job is to load it into memory, parse with some XML parser and search for `uses-permission` tag.
It looks like this `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.XXX"/>`.

To unzip the xml from Archive i would recommend [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27050680/3711660)
You should modify it to grab only the .xml file, and 
[Documentation of ZipEntry](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/zip/ZipEntry.html) is telling that it has a `.getName()` method. 
I will leave the xml-parsing research for you ([that tutorial is not bad](http://www.sitepoint.com/learning-to-parse-xml-data-in-your-android-app/)), and yes, its obviously possible.

**EDIT:** I found one library that could possibly do it - [APK-Parser Github](https://github.com/xiaxiaocao/apk-parser), but it was not tested on android. Some users are reporting some issues on android L

```
try(ApkParser apkParser = new ApkParser(new File(filePath))) {
     for (String permission: apkMeta.getUsesPermissions()) {
        Log.d("APK PERM",permission);
    }
}
```