# Android Permission Real Time Seeking during installation

Tags: java, android, permissions, android-package-managers

How can I check the installation of the new application to my phone through my android application.Also I need to scan the permissions the installing app is seeking.
Inshort the feature called on-install scan in CM security is used and I want to implement it in my app,please help me with the code.
My problem statement is ,I have an app that should do the following 
1.While installing a new apps ,my app must seek what permission the installing app requires
2 I have to say it is a malicious app if it contains some predefined set of permission

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get App's Permission for each app? how to do it programmatically on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385957/how-to-get-apps-permission-for-each-app-how-to-do-it-programmatically-on-andro)

Answer (score 0):

Use package manager and a concrete mask, for example

```
PackageManager p = context.getPackageManager(); final List<PackageInfo> appinstall = p.getInstalledPackages(PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS | PackageManager.GET_PROVIDERS)
```

Comment: Thank for the answer ,but I need to get those permissions when the new app is installing not after installation .