# How to get permissions of an installed app

Tags: android

Please help... i'm new to android development...i have search about my problem but didn't get any solution...
i have also tried:
[Didn't understand it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385957/how-to-get-apps-permission-for-each-app-how-to-do-it-programmatically-on-andro)

I have get a list of all installed apps so now i want show all the permissions of each application in a textview when click on it

***List of all installed apps:***

**Main Activity:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ListView userInstalledApps = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.installed_app_list);

    List<AppList> installedApps = getInstalledApps();
    AppAdapter installedAppAdapter = new AppAdapter(MainActivity.this, installedApps);
    userInstalledApps.setAdapter(installedAppAdapter);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

private List<AppList> getInstalledApps() {
    List<AppList> res = new ArrayList<AppList>();
    List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < packs.size(); i++) {
        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
        if ((isSystemPackage(p) == false)) {
            String appName = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
            Drawable icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());
            res.add(new AppList(appName, icon));
        }
    }
    return res;
}

private boolean isSystemPackage(PackageInfo pkgInfo) {
    return ((pkgInfo.applicationInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) ? true : false;
}


}
```

**AppList Class:**

```
 public class AppList {

private String name;
Drawable icon;

public AppList(String name, Drawable icon) {
    this.name = name;
    this.icon = icon;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public Drawable getIcon() {
    return icon;
}
```

}

**AppAdapter:**

```
public class AppAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private List<AppList> listStorage;

public AppAdapter(Context context, List<AppList> customizedListView) {
    layoutInflater =(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    listStorage = customizedListView;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listStorage.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ViewHolder listViewHolder;
    if(convertView == null){
        listViewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.installed_app_list, parent, false);

        listViewHolder.textInListView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_app_name);
        listViewHolder.imageInListView = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.app_icon);
        convertView.setTag(listViewHolder);
    }else{
        listViewHolder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
    }
    listViewHolder.textInListView.setText(listStorage.get(position).getName());
    listViewHolder.imageInListView.setImageDrawable(listStorage.get(position).getIcon());

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder{

    TextView textInListView;
    ImageView imageInListView;
}
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#eceaea">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/installed_app_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:scrollbars="none" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

**installed_apps_list.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/app_icon"
    android:layout_width="48dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/hello_world"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="8dp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/list_app_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/app_icon"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/app_icon"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"/>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

> This is what i have done....i mean i get all the installed apps now i
>   want each app permissions when click on any listed app....

Comment: have you taken required permissions in manifest?

Comment: no i didn't.....

Comment: Are you getting  instaled packges?

Comment: @Baadsha you'd better learn from Permission basics from Android's official documentation. Don't use the codes you don't know how does it work.

Comment: @Baadsha, you are on finishing line...you need to get permission while fetching installed app and then show it on `listview` item click. Please check my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

You need retrieve `PackageName` as well along with `Permissions` like below.

```
PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> packages =pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

for (ApplicationInfo applicationInfo : packages) 
{
   Log.d("test", "App: " + applicationInfo.name + " Package: " + applicationInfo.packageName);

   try 
   {
      PackageInfo packageInfo = pm.getPackageInfo(applicationInfo.packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

      //Get Permissions
      String[] requestedPermissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;

      if(requestedPermissions != null) 
      {
         for (int i = 0; i < requestedPermissions.length; i++) 
         {
            Log.d("test", requestedPermissions[i]);
         }
      }
   } 
   catch (NameNotFoundException e) 
   {
      e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

Add `field` permission in your modal class `AppList` and populate it.

Add listener on your listview `userInstalledApps` like this

```
userInstalledApps.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
        {
            AppList appList = installedAppAdapter.getItem(position);
            String permissions = appList.getPermission();
            //Do whatever you want with permissions here.
        }
    });
```

Please make correction in your `AppAdapter` class by this piece of code

```
@Override
public AppList getItem(int position) {
    return listStorage.get(position);
}
```

**As your need check use below code** replace respective code with this

```
private List<AppList> getInstalledApps()
{
    List<AppList> res = new ArrayList<AppList>();
    List<PackageInfo> packs = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < packs.size(); i++) {
        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
        if ((isSystemPackage(p) == false))
        {
            String appName = p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(getPackageManager()).toString();
            Drawable icon = p.applicationInfo.loadIcon(getPackageManager());

            try {
                PackageInfo packageInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(p.applicationInfo.packageName, PackageManager.GET_PERMISSIONS);

                //Get Permissions
                String[] requestedPermissions = packageInfo.requestedPermissions;
                StringBuilder sbPermissionSt = new StringBuilder();

                if(requestedPermissions != null)
                {
                    for (int j = 0; j < requestedPermissions.length; j++)
                    {
                        Log.d("test", requestedPermissions[j]);
                        sbPermissionSt.append(requestedPermissions[j]+",");
                    }
                }

                res.add(new AppList(appName, icon, sbPermissionSt.toString()));
            }
            catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException nme)
            {
                nme.printStackTrace();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

**Your AppList.java**

```
public class AppList
{
private String name;
Drawable icon;
private String permissions;

public AppList(String name, Drawable icon, String permissions)
{
    this.name = name;
    this.icon = icon;
    this.permissions = permissions;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public Drawable getIcon() {
    return icon;
}

public String getPermissions() {
    return permissions;
}

public void setPermissions(String permissions) {
    this.permissions = permissions;
}
```

}

Add this code after setting adapter to your listview (attach listener)

```
userInstalledApps.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id)
        {
            AppList appList = installedAppAdapter.getItem(position);
            String permissions = appList.getPermissions();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, permissions, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: what is meant by field permission

Comment: I was asking add one more attribute `String permissions;` to your `AppList` class and create it's `setter/getter` to hold installed app permission like `private String name;Drawable icon;`

Comment: and please a lil bit explain this........how to implement according my application?......

PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> packages =pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

for (ApplicationInfo applicationInfo : packages) 
{
.
.
.
.

Comment: @Baadsha, I have added code as per your need please use that. Use my getInstalledApps() method, class and listview item click listener.

Comment: i debug the code its work well but the permissions in onitemclick is null ....i mean the Toast is showing nothing but an empty Toast

AppList appList = installedAppAdapter.getItem(position);
            String permissions = appList.getPermissions();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, permissions, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: @Baadsha, there was minor bug while looping over permission array I have updated that. This is the updated code `for (int j = 0; j < requestedPermissions.length; j++)
                        {
                            Log.d("test", requestedPermissions[j]);
                            sbPermissionSt.append(requestedPermissions[j]+",");
                        }`

Comment: @Baadsha, simple change `i` to `j` while getting permission from `requestedPermissions[j]`

Comment: what is sbPermissionSt??

Comment: A variable to hold permission. You can use that as per your requirement Check code.

Comment: @Baadsha, you missed something or not able to implement my code. Please start copy again. It will definitely work :)

Comment: this line is giving me an error....
res.add(new AppList(appName, icon, sbPermissionSt.toString()));

Comment: (appName, icon, sbPermissionSt.toString()))

Comment: errors gone.... i have copied and paste all the code.... but still getting NULL POINTER EXCEPTION on list item click

Comment: Man please help yourself you are doing silly mistake somewhere in code.

Comment: If you are using Android Studio replace your src folder by this src folder [src]https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4DZREKCN1gkUExxbjdnTUpPalE

Comment: @Baadsha, Yes you did it  :) Please mark it as answer.